# tweetinvi, I can't retrieve messages

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I want to monitor retrieve messages so that the bot can respond to them.

I can send pm using tweetinvi but for some reason, I can't get it to retrieve any of the messages in that account. GetLastMessage always returns a null.

I have tried the following:

in this test, I have a timer that runs every 1s and pols the messages.

```
private static void OnTwitterTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<IMessage> MSG  = controller.GetLatestMessagesReceived(); ; // Message.GetLatestMessagesReceived(100);

        if (MSG != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MSG.ElementAt(0).SenderScreenName + MSG.ElementAt(0).Text);

            if ((MSG.ElementAt(0).SenderId == ####MYID#####) & (MSG.ElementAt(0).Text == "?"))
            {
                Message.PublishMessage(tweet, ####MYID#####);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.WriteLine(MSG.ElementAt(0).SenderScreenName + MSG.ElementAt(0).Text);
                Console.ResetColor();
                Message.DestroyMessage(MSG.ElementAt(0));
            }
        }
    } catch
    {
        }

}
```

I have also tried

```
   private static void OnTwitterTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var latestMessagesSent = Message.GetLatestMessagesSent();
            var latestMessagesSentParameter = new MessagesSentParameters();
            latestMessagesSentParameter.PageNumber = 239823;
            var latestMessagesSentFromParameter = Message.GetLatestMessagesSent(latestMessagesSentParameter);

            if (latestMessagesSentFromParameter != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Messages Send : ");
                foreach (var mms in latestMessagesSentFromParameter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- '{0}'", mms.Text);
                }

            }
        } catch
        {
        }

    }
```

I also tried using

IAuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
authenticatedUser.GetLatestMessagesReceived();

I am using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
//using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;

// REST API
using Tweetinvi;
using Tweetinvi.Models;
using Tweetinvi.Parameters;

// STREAM API
using Tweetinvi.Streaming;
using Stream = Tweetinvi.Stream;

// Others
using Tweetinvi.Exceptions; // Handle Exceptions
using Tweetinvi.Core.Extensions; // Extension methods provided by Tweetinvi
using Tweetinvi.Models.DTO; // Data Transfer Objects for Serialization
using Tweetinvi.Json; // JSON static classes to get json from Twitter.
```

Comment: The app does have read, write and DM permissions

Comment: So found the issue. I had to regenerate the tokens as changing the permissions is encoded in the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Your app must have permission to read and write on twitter API.